# Wpf Expression Call-out clipping

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have a User control, which has a grid as a root elemnt.
I want to have a call out box pop up under my control that gives extra info.
The problem I have is the height and width of the of the call-out is linked to the grid size.
Making the control very small shrinks the call out box.
How do I make the callout size preferably size to the text content ?

Here is the UserControl

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WpfUserControlsTest.Door"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="86" d:DesignHeight="19">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle  Fill="Red"/>
    <ed:Callout AnchorPoint="-0.012,1.349" CalloutStyle="RoundedRectangle" Content="Callout text in here" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" FontSize="14.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="91,-72,-167,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162"/>
</Grid>
```

Here it is used

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfUserControlsTest" x:Class="WpfUserControlsTest.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <local:Door HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23.333" Canvas.Left="28.666" Canvas.Top="83.333" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Here is the result
[image: Here is the clipped callout]

Comment: First please remove Width="162" for ed:Callout.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, setting explicit `Height` and/or `Width` dimensions and/or `Margin`s will stop a `UserControl` from sizing itself. If you want the `UserControl` to re-size itself to the size of its content, simply remove the explicit layout and dimension values that you have set.

Comment: Thanks for looking but that not what I want. If I did that the call-out box would have no size or position.

Comment: It would only have no size if it had no content and position has no relation to size... setting the position will not affect the size. All the same, suit yourself. :)